# Python timeit: How to initialize arguments for timed function before every repetition?

Tags: python, python-2.7, initialization, arguments, timeit

Let's say I'm trying to measure the execution time of a sorting function, here is my code:

```
import timeit

def time_algo(sort_fun, input_seq, num=100):
    '''
    Time how long it takes to sort sequence 'input_seq' using
    function 'sort_fun'. Take min of 'num' times.
    '''
    foo = list(input_seq)
    wrapped = wrapper(sort_fun, foo)
    return min(timeit.repeat(wrapped, repeat=num, number=1))

def wrapper(func, *args):
    def wrapped():
        return func(*args)
    return wrapped

print time_algo(list.sort, [10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1], num = 100)
```

The problem is that after the first execution of `sort_fun`, the input list is already sorted, and it's running on a sorted list for the rest of `num - 1` times.

How can I initialize the arguments for the input function (in this case execute `foo = list(input_seq)`) before every repetition of function timing? Or what would be the proper way to do this using the `timeit` module (I need accurate results so i don't want to use other timing methods like `time.clock()` etc.)?

Comment: Do you mind having the timings for a copy included in the `timing`-result?

Comment: Thats exactly what I'm trying to avoid here :)

Comment: That's going to be hard.
You'll want your function under test to not modify its arguments. Or, you'll need to do a copy for every call. But unless the function takes a significant amount of time to run, you (or the timeit implementation) can't start and stop timing around every call, it's too short, that's the point of `num > 1`.

Comment: or very easy: Don't sort in-place :)

Comment: ok, sorry, I see that you already run just once per repeat and take the smallest, so this would only be useful for a function that takes at the very least a few milliseconds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this modified `time_algo()` does what you want:

```
def time_algo(sort_fun, input_seq, num=100):                                                        
    '''                                                                                             
    Time how long it takes to sort sequence 'input_seq' using                                       
    function 'sort_fun'. Take min of 'num' times.                                                   
    '''                                                                                             
    foo = list(input_seq)                                                                           
    wrapped = wrapper(sort_fun, foo)                                                                
    def reset_foo():                                                                                
        foo[:] = list(input_seq)                                                                    
    return min(timeit.timeit(wrapped, setup=reset_foo, number=1) for _ in range(num))
```

This re-copies input_seq to list foo before each timeit(). There less-fancy / more-manual ways of doing it that could be more general: you could write a plain loop which copies the input, makes a new wrapper, and calls timeit.

... but as commented above, you really want multiple iterations, per timeit, and for that you really want to be timing a function which does not modify its inputs.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it's not beautiful but it looks like it does what I've asked for. On a side note, do You think that including the copying timing and increasing the number parameter in timeit function will give me more reliable results or this is the way to go? For me this look better, at least theoretically..

Comment: It depends on how long your function takes to run on a realistic-sized test input. If it takes a "long" time (perhaps 10 milliseconds or more) then the above is probably fine. If it doesn't take that long but runs many times (in your use case), then input gathering/copying is probably more significant, so that should be realistic and included in the timed function. If it doesn't take long and doesn't run many times then it doesn't matter.